# The speak function should work each time a question comes on screen, but it does not work for very first question and works fine after that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment-project

I have made a component using react-speech-kit, it should speak the question whenever it comes on screen, but the speak function does not work for the very first question and works fine after that.

```
import { useSpeechSynthesis } from 'react-speech-kit';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const TextToSpeech = ({question}) => {
  const {speak} = useSpeechSynthesis();

  useEffect(() => {
    speak({text:question});
  }, [question]);

}

export default TextToSpeech;
```

Comment: How is `question` being passed and updated? Is this a single component whose `question` keeps getting updated, or does the parent component create multiple `TextToSpeech` component, one for each `question`?

Comment: It is a single component whose question keeps updating.

Comment: Try `console.log`ging `question` right before `speak()`, check if the first `question` is being passed correctly, or if it is being passed correctly but maybe `useSpeechSynthesis` is async and needs a bit of time to initialise. Try to locate the problem more.

Comment: Tried this also, the question is coming correct but still not working :
    import { useSpeechSynthesis } from 'react-speech-kit';
    import { useEffect } from 'react';

    const TextToSpeech = ({question}) => {
      const {speak} = useSpeechSynthesis();
  
    async function speakQuestion(){
        await speak({text:question});
    }
      useEffect(() => {
          console.log(question);
          speakQuestion();
      }, [question]);

    }

    export default TextToSpeech;

Comment: check if `useSpeechSynthesis` is async and try `const {speak} = await useSpeechSynthesis()`?